# Office 2010 Beta - Keeps downloading when I open new documents

Tags: microsoft-office, office-2010-beta

I installed Office 2010 Beta a few weeks ago and everytime I open any Office document (ppt, doc, xls etc.), the splash screen appears, and text under the logo says "Downloading Microsoft [Word/Excelt/Powerpoint]".

Am I missing something here? Is there a reason it keeps downloading, whatever it may be.

Is there a way to download everything so it doesn't have to keep downloading (downloading makes documents load slow also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this a few times... A reinstall did the job.

At the end of the day, it is still beta!

You can report this at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/dashboard/?wa=wsignin1.0)